# Application not running via using Testflight

Tags: ios, ipa, testflight

I have done with application and tested. It is successfully working as well as in device.
Then, I have successfully created "IPA" file of an application. Then upload it on cloud via testflight.

But, when installing an application via testflight in device, it's not running and crashing.
Is there any issue regarding "Deployment target" or any other?

Tell me if anyone knows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean it fails to install?  Or that it crashes when you try and run it?

Comment: Without the crash report we really can't say. There are to may things that could have gone wrong. I would suggest that you integrate the testflight library so you will be able to track crashes.

Comment: @KarlMonaghan : I can install. But after installing, it crashes whenever trying to run.

Comment: You could install something like [System Console](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8) to see if there's anything in the logs or as rckoenes suggests try the TestFlight crash reporting (but I think the app would have to start once for that to work).

Comment: Did you try innstall the generated IPA to the device before you uploaded to testflight? Did you try to delete app before reinstall it from testflight? Did you try to regenerate the IPA? Did you find the solution?